# Existence of analytic function in disk algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, analytic-functions

Does there exist an analytic function $f\in A(\mathbb{D})$, where $A(\mathbb{D})$ is the disk algebra, such that $f(0)=0$ and the real part of $f(z)$ is strictly positive?

Comment: Suppose it does. Let $g(z)=exp(-f(z))$, then $g\in A(D)$. Now use the maximum principle to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Can't we argue even more simply that $f(0)$ is the average of $f(z)$ over $|z|=1$?